# incremental OL using letters (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, list, count, increment

I'm trying to dynamically add a span to an ol, where the counter should be in letters. eg:
A result
B result
C result
etc etc

I've got this code which is great for using numbers but I've no idea what to do to it to make the numbers into letters

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.results ol').each(function () {
       jQuery(this).find('li').each(function (i) {
           i = i+1;
           jQuery(this).prepend('<span class="marker">' + i + '</span>');
       });
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm):

Lower Case:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
     jQuery('.results ol').each(function() {
       jQuery(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
           jQuery(this).prepend('<span class="marker">&#' + (i+97) + ';</span>');
       });
    });
})
```

Upper Case:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
     jQuery('.results ol').each(function() {
       jQuery(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
           i = i+1;
           jQuery(this).prepend('<span class="marker">&#' + (i+65) + ';</span>');
       });
    });
})
```

Of course you'll run out of letters if you have more than 26 results.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, will you need to mark more than 26 results? Also just curious why you aren't just using CSS? `.results ol li { list-style-type: upper-alpha }` or `.results ol li { list-style-type: lower-alpha }`